# Jquery unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery v1.11.3 and I have an error when trying to evaluate a selector that has been escaped because of meta characters:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #foo\\/bar\\.buzz

But if I try to evaluate it in the console right away it works:

```
$('#foo\\/bar\\.buzz')
[<li id=​"foo/​bar.buzz" >​…​</li>​]
```

My simple question is why is the selector not working at eval time but works in the console?

Comment: @Yeldar, the period has to be escaped (not sure about the forward slash) in order to prevent it from being parsed as a class selector.

Comment: And, yes, what is the sense, in general, in using so complicated and impractical IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works properly. Problem must be somewhere else.

```js
$(function(){
  snippet.log('Yahooooooo: ' + $('#foo\\/bar\\.buzz').text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div id='foo/bar.buzz'>test</div>
```

Comment: ...There is a close-vote for this very reason, please use it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, Sure. but we also need to show that code works.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Well I'm still open to get an answer on the `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` signification then. @Satpal thanks for your answer also.

Comment: @plus- I'm not getting that error on either chrome or firefox, would you mind providing a simple example that gives such an error?

Comment: To all. That was a stupid mistake on my end, I trusted the console log, in the end I had 4 backslashs in my string while I was only seeing 2 in the console